# Count with input value 0.00

Tags: javascript

I have written a code that will count for me the difference between input value field one and input value field to, but it seems not working when i try to count with the value of 0.00. Can anbody help?

Here is my code

```
function getMutaties(el) {
                            el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2);
                            var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("start_balance").value);
                            var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("end_balance").value);

                            var totalValue = numVal2 - numVal1
                            document.getElementById("mutations").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
                            getVerschil();
                        }
```

Here are my input fields:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Begin saldo" name="start_balance" id="start_balance" onchange="setTwoNumberDecimal(this)"  onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)">

<input type="text" placeholder="Eind saldo" name="end_balance" id="end_balance" onchange="getMutaties(this)" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)">
```

Here is the setTwoNumberDecimal function:

```
function setTwoNumberDecimal(el) {
     el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2);
  };
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: `var v = 3.65 - 0.00;
var v1 = v.toFixed(2);
alert(v1);`....this is working fine

also, `var v = 3 - 0.00;
var v1 = v.toFixed(2);
alert(v1);` ... is working fine

Comment: Check on your code... `el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2);`...i could not find a place in your code where you are using **el.value** further

Comment: I use el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2); to round the input value to 2 decimals.

Comment: I use el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2); to round the input value to 2 decimals. The point is if i put 0.00 in start balance and 0.00 in end balance the totalvalue will still be empty. as i mention in the code:

Comment: var totalValue = numVal2 - numVal1
document.getElementById("mutations").value = totalValue.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 1):

setTwoNumberDecimal will throw an error when "0.00" is provided

```js
function setTwoNumberDecimal(el) {
     el.value = (parseFloat(el.value) || el.value).toFixed(2);
};
```

**parseFloat("0.00")** will be cast to false in `(parseFloat(el.value) || el.value)`
and **el.value** will remain string and you cannot call **.toFixed(2)** on string.